# How to square or raise to a power (elementwise) a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to square a 2D numpy array (elementwise) and I have tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
print a^2, '\n'
print a*a
```

that yields:

```
[[2 3]
[0 1]]

[[0 1]
[4 9]]
```

Clearly, the notation `a*a` gives me the result I want and not `a^2`.

I would like to know if another notation exists to raise a numpy array to the power of 2 or N? Instead of `a*a*a*..*a`.

Comment: [`numpy.power`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

Comment: In Python power operator is `**`.

Comment: `^` is [bitwise `xor`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), not power.

Comment: Thanks these three comments cover exactly the information I was looking for!

Comment: Not to be snarky, but google would have done the same for you. This question is rather trivial; its not like numpy doesn't come with excellent documentation.

Comment: @saullo thanks for your answer and for pointing out the differences in performance of the two approaches.

Comment: @jmb_louis you're welcome! I hope you liked it and that it clarified for you the differences... just as a side note, in C it is usually faster to do `a*a` (being `a` a float, double or integer) than `a**2` , because the latter involves a function call

Comment: Google keywords: what's being asked for here is a [hadamard power of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2749724/389109)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The fastest way is to do `a*a` or `a**2` or `np.square(a)` whereas `np.power(a, 2)` showed to be considerably slower.

`np.power()` allows you to use different exponents for each element if instead of `2` you pass another array of exponents. From the comments of @GarethRees I just learned that this function will give you different results than `a**2` or `a*a`, which become important in cases where you have small tolerances.

I've timed some examples using NumPy 1.9.0 MKL 64 bit, and the results are shown below:

```
In [29]: a = np.random.random((1000, 1000))

In [30]: timeit a*a
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop

In [31]: timeit a**2
100 loops, best of 3: 2.77 ms per loop

In [32]: timeit np.power(a, 2)
10 loops, best of 3: 71.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: `np.power` computes a different result too.

Comment: @GarethRees I checked that with `np.allclose(np.power(a, 2), a**2)` and it gave me `True`...

Comment: If `a=0.46002700024131926` then `np.power(a, 2)` → 0.21162484095102674 but `a * a` → 0.21162484095102677.

Comment: @GarethRees that's interesting... and not captured by the default tolerance of `np.allclose()`, thank you!

Comment: Of course that's close enough for `np.allclose` (where `atol` defaults to 1e-08), but sometimes you want a result that's as exact as possible (given the constraints of floating point).

Comment: @GarethRees I've added your observation to the answer... thank you again!

Comment: np.square(x) seems faster than x**2

Comment: @everitt I just did a test comparing `np.square(x)` with `x*x` with `x**2` and the three gave practically the same timing for an array of length `1e7`. I edited the answer with this new suggestion

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.power.__doc__

power(x1, x2[, out])

First array elements raised to powers from second array, element-wise.

Raise each base in `x1` to the positionally-corresponding power in
`x2`.  `x1` and `x2` must be broadcastable to the same shape.

Parameters
----------
x1 : array_like
    The bases.
x2 : array_like
    The exponents.

Returns
-------
y : ndarray
    The bases in `x1` raised to the exponents in `x2`.

Examples
--------
Cube each element in a list.

>>> x1 = range(6)
>>> x1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> np.power(x1, 3)
array([  0,   1,   8,  27,  64, 125])

Raise the bases to different exponents.

>>> x2 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
>>> np.power(x1, x2)
array([  0.,   1.,   8.,  27.,  16.,   5.])

The effect of broadcasting.

>>> x2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]])
>>> x2
array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]])
>>> np.power(x1, x2)
array([[ 0,  1,  8, 27, 16,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  8, 27, 16,  5]])
>>>
```

### Precision

As per the discussed observation on numerical precision as per @GarethRees objection in comments:

```
>>> a = numpy.ones( (3,3), dtype = numpy.float96 ) # yields exact output
>>> a[0,0] = 0.46002700024131926
>>> a
array([[ 0.460027,  1.0,  1.0],
       [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
       [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0]], dtype=float96)
>>> b = numpy.power( a, 2 )
>>> b
array([[ 0.21162484,  1.0,  1.0],
       [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
       [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0]], dtype=float96)

>>> a.dtype
dtype('float96')
>>> a[0,0]
0.46002700024131926
>>> b[0,0]
0.21162484095102677

>>> print b[0,0]
0.211624840951
>>> print a[0,0]
0.460027000241
```

### Performance

```
>>> c    = numpy.random.random( ( 1000, 1000 ) ).astype( numpy.float96 )

>>> import zmq
>>> aClk = zmq.Stopwatch()

>>> aClk.start(), c**2, aClk.stop()
(None, array([[ ...]], dtype=float96), 5663L)                #   5 663 [usec]

>>> aClk.start(), c*c, aClk.stop()
(None, array([[ ...]], dtype=float96), 6395L)                #   6 395 [usec]

>>> aClk.start(), c[:,:]*c[:,:], aClk.stop()
(None, array([[ ...]], dtype=float96), 6930L)                #   6 930 [usec]

>>> aClk.start(), c[:,:]**2, aClk.stop()
(None, array([[ ...]], dtype=float96), 6285L)                #   6 285 [usec]

>>> aClk.start(), numpy.power( c, 2 ), aClk.stop()
(None, array([[ ... ]], dtype=float96), 384515L)             # 384 515 [usec]
```