# Python numpy.square vs **

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a difference between `numpy.square` and using the `**` operator on a Numpy array?

From what I can see it yields the same result.

Any differences in efficiency of execution?

An example for clarification:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[2, 2],[2, 2]])

In [3]: np.square(A)
Out[3]: 
array([[4, 4],
       [4, 4]])

In [4]: A ** 2
Out[4]: 
array([[4, 4],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: Use `timeit` to check which one is faster, if this is what you are after.

Comment: They are not quite the same, `np.square()` does an element wise squaring, whereas some classes e.g. matrix the `__pow__()` operator does something different. For array class they are the same. Change `array` to `matrix` and see the difference.

Comment: Also, x**2 (where x is a numpy array) might give you some negative elements, while np.square(x) does not

Comment: @BlackBear can you explain a bit more on your comment?  why would x**2 give negative elements? Is there any documentation for this issue?

Comment: @AshlinJP integer overflow: `np.array([4000000000])**2 -> array([-2446744073709551616])`. However `np.square` does the same, so I am not sure why I said that. (Also note you get a warning and `inf` if you try with a float)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can check the execution time to get clear picture of it

```
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: A = np.array([[2, 2],[2, 2]])
In [7]: %timeit np.square(A)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 923 ns per loop
In [8]: %timeit A ** 2
1000000 loops, best of 3: 668 ns per loop
```

Comment: np.square might be faster with larger matrixes, also: `sq = np.square
 %timeit sq(A)` -> `680ns`

Answer (score 28):

For most appliances, both will give you the same results.
Generally the standard pythonic `a*a` or `a**2` is faster than the `numpy.square()` or `numpy.pow()`, but the `numpy` functions are often more flexible and precise.
If you do calculations that need to be very accurate, stick to `numpy` and probably even use other datatypes `float96`.

For normal usage `a**2` will do a good job and way faster job than `numpy`.
The guys in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870923/how-to-square-or-raise-to-a-power-elementwise-a-2d-numpy-array) gave some good examples to a similar questions.

Comment: `**` of an numpy array is just syntactic sugar for ndarray.__pow__().

Comment: right, I was pretty unclear about the type of the argument (numpy or not)

Comment: How can you say that is more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

@saimadhu.polamuri and @foehnx/@Lumos

On my machine, currently, NumPy performs faster than **.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [3]: %timeit A ** 2

256 ns ± 0.922 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit np.square(A)

240 ns ± 0.759 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)