# Python: Precision of numpy.square vs **

Tags: python, numpy

What is the relative precision between using `numpy.square()` versus the pythonic `**`? As seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361856/python-numpy-square-vs/29362280), it seems like `numpy.square()` is more precise, but to what degree? (Also, I recognize that the link I am referencing to may be outdated.) Thanks!

Comment: Can you please quote the passage that makes it "seem like `numpy.square()` is more precise"?

Comment: It's not the method of squaring, but the thing that's being squared, that causes issues with precision. A `numpy` array contains fixed-with integers, not arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Numpy is implemented in C, so for performance purposes, you must use specific memory-sized datatypes.

Comment: Technically you can build a numpy array containing objects, and those objects could then be multi-precision Python integers. Simply you cannot use `numpy` vectorized operations on that...

Comment: @CaptainTrojan In the linked thread, foehnx mentions that "`numpy` functions are often more flexible and precise."

Comment: @chepner Oh, that makes so much sense! Thank you!!

Comment: What are you trying to `square`?  A float?  int?  Large int?

Comment: @hpaulj I am trying to square a float.

Comment: I don't see why there should be a diifference, taking a float64 and returning the same.  I suppose you could compare the values with those produced by `mpmath` set to a higher precision.

Comment: @hpaulj Hmm that also makes sense -- there might be something else going on in my code then too -- thank you for referring to `mpmath`: it seems like an amazing way to increase the precision!

Answer (score -4):

It is true that numpy.square() is more precise. However, this is not the case in general.

This difference arises from the way both functions are implemented. In particular, numpy.square() uses a trick to do a single-instruction calculation on the whole array without any explicit looping, and this trick is guaranteed to give exact results for the special case of a square.

In contrast, ** is not a built-in operation, but rather a special syntax for calling the **pow** method of its left argument. In this case, the result is guaranteed to be exact only if both arguments can be exactly represented in IEEE 754 double precision. This is not the case for a ** 2 unless the absolute value of the exponent is less than 53 (i.e., unless the exponent is less than the precision of the double-precision representation).

In general, it is best to avoid powers (**) and use numpy.square() instead.

Comment: Numpy's vectorization of operations has nothing to do with the precision of floating point operations.