# R-style formulas when implementing a power (i.e. square) in a GLM misbehaves

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, glm

In the python code below, the glm model specification does not include the third power in the in model1 but it does in model2:

```
model1 = glm(formula="wage ~ workhours + workhours**3           + C(gender)", data=df, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
model2 = glm(formula="wage ~ workhours + np.power(workhours, 3) + C(gender)", data=df, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
```

Is this a bug? According to the documentation **x raises something to the power 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python numpy.square vs \*\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361856/python-numpy-square-vs)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Your link answers another question. The question is about patsy's interpretation of **, not python's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`**` in a formula is treated as a formula operator, not as regular exponentiation. (This is similar to how `^` works in an R formula.)

`(a+b+c+d)**3` means that the model should include `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and all interactions between these variables up to 3rd order.

`workhours**3` means that the model should include `workhours` and all interactions between... just `workhours`... up to 3rd order... but there are no such interaction terms, so it's equivalent to just `workhours`.

In contrast, `np.power(workhours, 3)` is treated as Python code, and computes the power you wanted.

statsmodels uses [patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for formula handling, so for full details on the formula language, you can check the [patsy docs](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html#the-formula-language).