# Difference between numpy power and ** for certain values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array where the entries in `f**2` differ from `f[i]**2`, but only for some specific value.

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision = 16)

f = np.array([ -40709.6555510835, -40708.6555510835, -33467.081758611654, -27653.379955714125])

f2 = f**2
# f2 = np.power(f,2)

print("outside loop", np.abs(f[1]**2 - f2[1]), np.abs(1.0 - f2[1] / f[1]**2), f.dtype, f[1].dtype, f2.dtype, f2[1].dtype)

for i, val in enumerate(f):        
    print("inside loop", i, np.abs(val**2 - f2[i]), np.abs(1.0 - f2[i] / val**2), val.dtype, f2.dtype, f2[i].dtype)
```

Produces output:

```
outside loop 2.384185791015625e-07 2.220446049250313e-16 float64 float64 float64 float64
inside loop 0 0.0 0.0 float64 float64 float64
inside loop 1 2.384185791015625e-07 2.220446049250313e-16 float64 float64 float64
inside loop 2 0.0 0.0 float64 float64 float64
inside loop 3 0.0 0.0 float64 float64 float64
```

I do note that this is a relative error on the order of epsilon.

This issue goes away when using `np.power` instead of `**` in the definition of `f2`.
Even so, why is `f[i]**2` not the same as the `i`th value of `f**2` (even if only for certain values in `f`).

I'm using python 3.10.6 and the latest numpy 1.26.4.

### Edit:

The fundamental issue is captured in:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.array([-40708.6555510835])
print((f[0])**2 - (f**2)[0])
```

which displays a value of

```
-2.384185791015625e-07
```

I would like to know why that specific number has this specific issue. If you'd like confirmation, or to try different values for `f`, see this [demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3SzNzC_KLShTySnMLKhUSixXyCrjyCvSKU0viC4oy80ryC0oy8_OKNQqKUpMzi4FMBVsFQzNNrjQgDVSXWFSUWKkRrWtiYG5goWdmCgSGBhbGprGaXGDtGhpp0QaxmlpaRgq6ChppQFoTxIdYDnUDzC0A).

Comment: I'm not sure *what* different algorithms are used for `**` and `power`, but for `x = -40708.6555510835`, you get similar results outside of NumPy for `x * x` and `x ** 2`. `np.power` appears to be using simple multiplication rather than a  single fast-exponentiation rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to square or raise to a power (elementwise) a 2D numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870923/how-to-square-or-raise-to-a-power-elementwise-a-2d-numpy-array)

Comment: I know that `**` is sugar for `np.ndarray.__pow__` (see discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361856/python-numpy-square-vs, for example). But that doesn't answer the question about why a specific value would have an issue.

Comment: There is a difference between when you are doing direct exponentiation ** operator on np array and doing it on element by element inside the for loop. Most probably doing ** on np.array might have different implementation like using np.power instead of directly using **. You should create another array and do element wise exponentiation and see. e.g f3 = []
for i, val in enumerate(f):
    f3.append(val**2)

Comment: Just inspecting `print(np.abs(f[1]**2 - f2[1]))` shows that this isn't to do with the looping.

Comment: If you changed your print statement to ```print(i, np.abs(1.0 - f2[i] / val**2 ) )``` would you come to the same conclusions?

Comment: What's `f.dtype` (or `np.power(f,2).dtype1).   I'm not getting your difference when I run your code.

Comment: When you iterate over `f` you convert each value from a numpy data type to a regular `float`.  So the difference comes down to how numpy takes a power vs. Python built-in.

Comment: @MarkRansom I get a NumPy float: [demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVDLSgQxEETwlK9o8JIsM8MkM3mM4Jcsi0RJMOAmIckq8y1e9qIf5dfYs6sH-1RUF13V9fGV1_aS4vn8eWq-N983t-GYU2kQT8e8gq0QM4l5qK495hJiS7mFFCvNxT2HihAegCtGiEeAQluKXeke-nnU4zIoicNHM8nuSpn_1DTNSg-j4VoaxbmSM5JCKzkNk14WKTWfuZCHzUCgg9_tBLmDC0a3nN5dob4T2z4VCB282VcIERw-4Iptjnp2TwDnEp-iYkv5VCkK8Rj0eGwfDqyDtma3sYxdy_jt5K-bHw)

Comment: @nocomment yes, I was just testing that for myself and noticed the same thing.  Interesting.

Comment: @praveenB and @lastchance and @hpaulj. I have added to the printing to show behavior inside/outside a loop, with an error as a 1-ratio, and showing everything has a `float64` `dtype`.

Comment: Thank-you @jmlarson. It's funny, though - at work (where I'm not at present) I got the odd behaviour with the OP's original version, but it disappeared when I tried to find relative error with the "1-" version. On my setup at home I'm not able to reproduce the problem: it's happily producing all 0's with both forms. Mysterious. Seems a version issue.

Comment: Thank you @lastchance. I note that an updated [demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZFNTsMwEIXFNqcYlY1TJSZO4vwgcZKqQoHawlJrW7YDylnYdAOn4QSchslPA0idhfX0Zkbvk-f90w7hxejz-aMPMm2-b77UyRoXQPcnO0DnQdtIW-pFeLRO6WBsUEZ7Yp14Vh4lPACr4iiSKHCwc64byA7SMquzllYci2VNwZPZav5bRVFWNc0aVvOmYqziJZp5XfGCFnXbcl6zkuV8PwbkmCC32zy6hUljmjVvwhGZ5Nif8MjG9MGrg4CjMXaTTEhPnsgd2-MqpLiKMl4bjGYXE-5gGcO2pIcwWJFM1qrzX7XaI5pxoBJ47Y6gNAj8O-G6IIiM72GpaHwWRKX_EqqVBfdXRnWNUY2M81Q8xV0FUyvYfNTltpcb_wA) shows the effect as well.

Comment: Note that the loop (as you noted yourself many times) has nothing to do with your example. The [mre] could be reduced to `f = np.array([-40708.6555510835, -33467.081758611654])` then `(f[0])**2 - (f**2)[0]`, compared if needed with `(f[1])**2 - (f**2)[1]`. (the first pair of parenthesis are useless, but help to read the problem. And why (f[0])**2 seems to be what you would get in with python's float `float(f[0])**2`, and not what you would get with numpy's `__pow__` aka `npy_pow` internally, tho `f[0]` is not a float but a `numpy.float64`.

Comment: I tested with numba. And in numba both `(f[0])**2` and `(f**2)[0]` have the same value, which is the same as `(f[0])**2` not `(f**2)[0]` outside numba. Even when you first store it in `val. Which tends (very poorly) to confirm that in C's numpy code, a scalar (a `numpy.float64`) is `**2`'ed with the same `npy_pow` whether it when `**2` an array or a single value. Not a very efficient proof. But I surmise numba uses numpy's `__pow__`

Comment: So, in other words, why `f = np.array([-40708.6555510835]); np.float64.__pow__(f[0],2) - np.ndarray.__pow__(f,2)[0]` is not 0

Comment: Note that the fact that `f=np.array([0.0]); f[0]**-1` and `f**-1` do not raise the same warning tends to prove that `**` is not the same inside numpy. Plus, in pure python `0.0**-1` is not a warning but an error. So this times `f[0]**-1` and `float(f[0])**-1` are not the same. So it is really all inside numpy's code. `np.ndarray.__pow__` does not use the same inline function as `np.float64.__pow__`

Comment: Which may make sense. When exponent is 2, a faster implementation of `x**2` is `x*x`. But for a single value, testing if exponent is 2 cost an operation (not an expensive one, but still, an operation. And it is certainly not the only test to make: 0 1 or -1 also eg). So, maybe for a scalar it is more efficient to directly rely on a more generic exponentiation. Where as, for an array, you can test once for all if exponent is 2 (same exponent for all elements). So at least, it makes sense that exponentiation on an array is not the same code as exponentiation on elements of that array.

Comment: For the "fundamental issue is captured in ..." I still think this may be a version-specific issue. With my setup (python 3.11.5, Numpy 1.26.0, running on Windows) that case gives an output of 0.0.

Comment: This issue seems to be libc dependant - when evaluating `(f[0])**2`, NumPy seems to call the C function `pow()` to implement it, which is part of libm. I found this by running OP's program under gdb, and putting a breakpoint on pow.

Comment: For scalars, NumPy `**` ends up in code generated from [this template](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src#L490). For doubles, this calls `npy_pow`, which is [defined](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_math.h#L199) as just `pow`.

Comment: For arrays, I believe it ends up in code generated from [this other template](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_umath_fp.dispatch.c.src#L216), which may call into an AVX-512 SIMD implementation depending on platform and NumPy configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results are different because `f**2` calls `numpy.square`, while `f[0]**2` and `numpy.power(f, 2)` call `numpy.power`.

---

`numpy.ndarray.__pow__` is written in C. [It looks like this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L579-L595):

```
static PyObject *
array_power(PyObject *a1, PyObject *o2, PyObject *modulo)
{
    PyObject *value = NULL;

    if (modulo != Py_None) {
        /* modular exponentiation is not implemented (gh-8804) */
        Py_INCREF(Py_NotImplemented);
        return Py_NotImplemented;
    }

    BINOP_GIVE_UP_IF_NEEDED(a1, o2, nb_power, array_power);
    if (fast_scalar_power(a1, o2, 0, &value) != 0) {
        value = PyArray_GenericBinaryFunction(a1, o2, n_ops.power);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The `value = PyArray_GenericBinaryFunction(a1, o2, n_ops.power);` is a Python function call to the `numpy.power` ufunc object, but first, it tries a `fast_scalar_power` function. This function tries to optimize exponentiation with common scalar powers, such as 2.

For the `f**2` operation, `fast_scalar_power` detects the exponent of 2, and [delegates](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L531-L533) the operation to `numpy.square`:

```
else if (exponent ==  2.0) {
    fastop = n_ops.square;
}
```

For `numpy.power(f, 2)`, this is of course a direct call to `numpy.power`. `numpy.power` doesn't go through `fast_scalar_power`, and doesn't have any special handling for an exponent of 2. (Depending on what underlying power implementation it hits, that implementation might still have special handling for 2, though.)

For scalars, I believe `numpy.float64.__pow__` [actually just calls](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L119) `array_power`:

```
static PyObject *
gentype_power(PyObject *m1, PyObject *m2, PyObject *modulo)
{
    if (modulo != Py_None) {
        /* modular exponentiation is not implemented (gh-8804) */
        Py_INCREF(Py_NotImplemented);
        return Py_NotImplemented;
    }

    BINOP_GIVE_UP_IF_NEEDED(m1, m2, nb_power, gentype_power);
    return PyArray_Type.tp_as_number->nb_power(m1, m2, Py_None);
}
```

so it hits `fast_scalar_power`, but [one of the first checks](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L513C1-L513C29) in `fast_scalar_power` is

```
if (PyArray_Check(o1) &&
```

An instance of `numpy.float64` does not pass `PyArray_Check`, which checks for objects whose type is exactly `numpy.ndarray`. Thus, the scalar goes through the general `numpy.power` code path.

Answer (score -2):

This might be a numpy bug, <strike>and might have been introduced in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7496.</strike>

I found this by searching through the changelog of numpy for "pow". It appears that both python and numpy use the standard library pow for doubles. So I was looking for differences on numpy's handling of ** on scalar values vs arrays.

<strike>I don't know if this is the actual cause of the behavior or not, but</strike> it's the only place that I've found so far where numpy doesn't use the standard library pow() function. And it lead me to a test that seems to duplicate the behavior you're seeing.

I see the exact same results on my core i7 iMac and on my M1 MBP.

```
>>> x = -40708.6555510835
>>> x**2
1657194636.7767615
>>> x * x
1657194636.7767618
>>> x**2 - x*x
-2.384185791015625e-07
```

So if I'm right, then saying `f[0]**2` uses the math lib pow function, and `(f**2)[0]` skips pow and multiplies the values together.

Comment: That change doesn't have anything to do with this. It only affects integer inputs - *both* sides have to be integers to hit that code path, not just the exponents.

Comment: I'm not familiar with numpy's source (or how it's doing templating). It seemed possible that it could produce a signature that was (double, int). But looking closer it looks like you're right, both vars have to be the same type. Perhaps there's another function that uses a similar loop (?).

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered very similar issues before which were caused by the fact that Python uses the traditional 80 bit floating point registers on x86, while NumPy uses SIMD which has 64 bit floating point.

Often this manifests as less precise floating point operations in NumPy, but they're not wrong.  Traditional x86 (technically x87) has extended precision due to its extra-wide registers, but that extended precision is not available when using SIMD instructions, nor on many other architectures.